# Replace a field in a line in a textfile

Tags: bash

I'm trying to grep the third field and replacing it in a specific line which's located in a text file.The textfile format goes like this :

```
username:password:access level:failed password attempts
```

I know how to grep the entire line and display it in a text file,but I'm not sure how to find and replace the third field.

I'm new to bash,so sorry for asking.

An example of the input would be :

```
"Change access level to : "
User enters in Restricted.
```

The output would be :
    Previously :

```
admin:password:Granted Access

Now :
admin:password:Restricted
```

The user enters the access level he wants only,and the access level's changed in the text file for the specific user and password.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Trying giving an example of the input and output.

Comment: Please show how you find the line.

Comment: @konsolebox Well,i'm new to bash. Something like this :  echo "$(grep "username:password" Details.txt)" That'll give me the specific line I want toc change,but what I want to change is the access level that the user inputs.

Comment: @Zenix Do you also ask for user's input with username and password?

Comment: @konsolebox Yeah,but I only ask for the access level that he wants to change it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically it's like this. You use `awk`:

```
read -p "Enter username: " username
read -p "Enter access level: " access
temp_file=$(mktemp)
awk -v username="$username" -v acccess="$access" -F : -v OFS=: '$1 == username { $3 = access } 1' password_file.txt > "$temp_file"
cat "$temp_file" > password_file.txt
rm -f "$temp_file"
```

- `-F :` sets field separator to `:`.
- `-v OFS=:` sets output field separator to `:`.
- `$1 == username` checks if first field matches username.
- `$3 = access` changes value of 3rd field to value of `access`.
- `1` basically commands printing the current record (line).
- `temp_file=$(mktemp)` creates a temporary file
- `cat "$temp_file" > password_file.txt` writes changes back to it.
- `rm -f "$temp_file"` removes temporary file.

To match based on the password as well:

```
awk -v username="$username" -v password="$password" -v acccess="$access" -F : -v OFS=: '$1 == username && $2 == password { $3 = access } 1' password_file.txt > "$temp_file"
```

And here's a solution for Bash in which no temporary file is necessary:

```
[[ BASH_VERSINFO -ge 4 ]] || exit 1
read -p "Enter username: " username
read -p "Enter access level: " access
readarray -t new_data < <(exec awk -v username="$username" -v acccess="$access" -F : -v OFS=: '$1 == username { $3 = access } 1' password_file.txt)
printf '%s\n' "${newdata[@]}" >password_file.txt
```

- `[[ BASH_VERSINFO -ge 4 ]] || exit 1` makes it sure that we're using Bash 4.0 or newer.
- `readarray -t new_data` saves output lines to array `new_data`.
- `printf '%s\n' "${newdata[@]}" > password_file.txt` writes back data from array to file.

And here's an alternative to `readarray`. It just needs Bash 3.1 or newer.

```
new_data=()
while IFS= read -r line; do new_data+=("$line"); done < <(exec awk -v username="$username" -v acccess="$access" -F : -v OFS=: '$1 == username { $3 = access } 1' password_file.txt)
```

For earlier versions supporting arrays, `new_data=("${new_data[@]}" "$line")` can also apply but is less efficient.

Comment: But the user only enters the updated access level he wants,so how do u match it to the specific line in the text file?

Comment: @Zenix Are you not specific to the username? Or do you care only about `admin`?

Comment: I'm specific to the username and password in the line, then for the particular line the access level's changed.

Comment: @Zenix Do usernames occur more than once in the file? If that is not the case you would only need to search based on the username. Basing on the password is not needed if the usernames are unique in the file.

Comment: @Zenix If the user only enters the access level, how do you choose the username? Do you choose the username of the user?

Comment: Yeah,the usernames occur more than once in the file. There's multiple entries, but all with different usernames. I need to change the specific access level for the specific username and password in the line of the textfile.

Comment: @Zenix I hope you follow me. If usernames and unique, you don't have to base from its password. You just have to base from the username.

Comment: The user enters his username and password, then chooses to update the access level.

Comment: @Zenix Ok so you get the username, password and access level from the user right? If that is the case the solution I gave you would already provide what you need. Anyway I also added a modification to the awk command in which you can also compare line with the password. But like I said it's not necessary if usernames are unique.

Comment: Yeah. Alright,thanks! Appreciated for the help. Sorry for the constant replies.

Comment: No worries. It's always fun to help.